# Python matrix addition without importing numpy

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I've been trying to add 2 matrices by using 2 for loops but I keep getting the error: `'int' object is not iterable` in the line `for i in len(B):`. What am I doing wrong?

```
def add (A,B):
    for i in len(B):
        for j in len(A):
            A[j][i] += B[i]
    return A

A = [[2, 8], [3, 7], [4, 5]]
B = [1, 2]
A = add(A,B)
print(C)
```

Comment: It's `range(len(B))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`len(b)` produces an `int`. [You can't iterate over an int.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for). To generate a sequence of `int`s upto `len(b)` use [`range`.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)

```
def add (A,B):
    for i in range(len(B)):
        for j in range(len(A)):
            A[j][i] += B[i]
    return A

A = [[2, 8], [3, 7], [4, 5]]
B = [1, 2]
A = add(A,B)
print(C)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an iterable object to iterate over in the [`for`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) loop. `len()` returns an `int` which is not iterable.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-pythons-iterator-iterable-and-iteration-protocols) post.

Try using [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#the-range-function) instead like

```
for i in range(len(B)):
    for j in range(len(A)):
        A[j][i] += B[i]
```